# Hide/unhide layout in list item

Tags: android, layout, view, visibility

I have a layout for list item, which consists of two `LinearLayouts`. What I want to achieve is: when item is clicked, second `LinearLayout` should become visible/gone, depending on the current visibility.

I am experimenting with this code:

```
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            view.getViewById(R.id.id_of_the_second_linear_layout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

However when item is clicked, several other linear layouts (in different items) become visible/hidden. Why?

Update:

Adapter:

```
public class ExpensesCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder { 

public ExpensesCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        super(context, R.layout.single_expense, cursor,
            new String[]{
                ExpenseContract._AMOUNT,
                CategoryContract._NAME,
                ExpenseContract._DATE
            },
            new int[]{
                R.id.expense_amount,
                R.id.expense_category,
                R.id.expense_date
            },
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        setViewBinder(this);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, viewGroup);

        final View expandablePanel = v.findViewById(R.id.expandable_panel);
        expandablePanel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                expandablePanel.setVisibility(view.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(ExpenseContract._AMOUNT)) {
            return handleAmountView((TextView) view, cursor);
        }
        else ...

        return false;
    }

    private boolean handleAmountView(TextView view, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;

        Double amount = ExpenseDbHelper.getAmount(cursor);
        String formattedAmount = new DecimalFormat("##.00").format(amount);

        textView.setText(formattedAmount);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Each item has LinearLayout already added in XML, I want to toggle visibility flag, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing your logic on wrong places. You want to listen clicks of views inside listitem. Write your logic in Adapter's `getView`  method. In your `getView` logic can be like this

```
ll1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ll2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

ll2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ll1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
```

Something like this.

Comment: Several items are updated when I add this code to the adapter, and click one item: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, viewGroup);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                View expandablePanel = view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_panel);
                toggleVisibility(expandablePanel);
                );
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

Comment: Can show this code in your question ? Also I see that you are not inflating any layout in getView()?

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll through the list items, some layouts will hide and un-hide, in that case, if you are targeting just one view to be visible at a time (that is just considering one cell at a time), then you could maintain the position of the item clicked, or the id, since you are using a `cursorAdapter`. Else if you are considering more than one cell then maintain a list where in you store each id of the cell that has been tapped on.

Pass the list or the single position value to the adpater, and in the getview compare the id or position and then perform the visiblity code.

Hope this hint helps.